# kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingApplicationIsPlayingDidChangeNotification Notificatoin Not Working

Tags: swift, appkit

I'm trying to use the MediaRemote framework to get access to music status on my mac. I tried to get the playing status in this way:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(onChange),
                                       name: Notification.Name("kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingApplicationIsPlayingDidChangeNotification"),
                                       object: nil)
```

but if i try to play and stop the music the method onChange doesn't get called.
I don't know if i have to do anything else due the fact that MediaRemote is a private framework.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, actually to get notified i had to call this method

```
void MRMediaRemoteRegisterForNowPlayingNotifications(dispatch_queue_t queue);
```